# Can I cross reference named module instances in SystemVerilog?

Tags: module, system-verilog

For example, is the following code legal (with regard to the way that the modules signals are mapped), or do I have to define explicit wires to connect the modules?

```
module A(
    output logic x;
);
module B(
    input logic y;
);

A instanceOfA();
B(
    .y(instanceOfA.x)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for simulation, but most synthesis tools do not accept hierarchical references.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. But it's better to take a common net, which which will be driven by multiple modules.

```
module top ();
  wire common;

  A instance_a (common);
  B instance_b (common);
endmodule
```